# Complexity of Simon's Problem

Tags: complexity-theory

In reading the Wiki article on Simon's Problem, the article states that it takes exponential time(in the classical version) to discover the secret string S that is inside the black box. Why is this black box problem not considered to be a one way function and are there any cryptographic primitives based on the hardness of discovering the secret string S. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A one-way function is a function $f$ such that $f(x)$ is easy to compute, but given $y$ in the range of $f$, it is hard to computer a preimage of $f$. Notice that there is no black-box involved. The idea is that $f$ "looks like" a black box that applies $f$ in the sense that you can apply $f$ but cannot do much more, and in particular cannot invert $f$ (or even learn anything about the inverse).

The goal of cryptography is to come up with cryptographically secure algorithms. There is no place for a black box there. That said, when constructing protocols from primitives, we often treat the primitives as black boxes with certain properties. In some cases we can actually show that this point of view isn't general enough - we show that given one primitive as a black box, another primitive cannot be constructed, though perhaps such a construction is possible given access to the code of the first primitive.

Comment: :In terms of Simon's Problem, if you were using it as say a psuedorandom generator, you wouldn't give the adversary access to the input, the inputs could just be strings generated by linear feedback shift registers. So the problem is only described as "black box" when you are trying to prove its computational complexity but as an explicit device to generate random bits, you don't give the adversary access to the inputs.

Comment: In that case you'll have to satisfy some function implementing the black box, and the security assumption would be that Simon's problem with that particular function is difficult. It's not clear which function to use, though, and whether you can use this assumption to implement any cryptographic primitive.

Comment: If you use an XOR mask inside the box controlled by another secret string, the output has to be the result of one of two "promises" or positions of the XOR mask relative to the input bits and the primary secret string S. It therefore becomes a sorting problem for the adversary, that would be your lower bound arguement.

Comment: In cryptography there are no black boxes. The idea in cryptography is to come up with functions that *look* like black boxes. What you suggest can be converted into some particular function, that may or may not be breakable. It's certainly not the case that your suggested breaking method is the only one possible, and so your lower bound "argument" doesn't work.

Comment: OK, you are right. Nice comments!